# Is there any documentation for Guacamole on Windows?? Or any C# based web RDP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, rdp, guacamole

I am looking forward to build a web Based RDP client for one of my projects. Unfortunately, I could find only one Open Source project for this i.e. [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org).
I tried to go through the documentation, but It was written in some alien language. I am a C#/ASP.net/jQuery developer and the documentation is pretty confusing to me.
I did not find any install package for Windows in the documentation, neither I found any compiling methods for windows.

Is there any alternative to Guacamole for windows ? I'd prefer C# based back end over HTML5.

If not, please tell me about windows documentation of Guacamole.

Any help would be highly apppreciated..!!
Thank you..!

Comment: You should add the link to the project: not everyone knows it :)
http://guac-dev.org/

Comment: done.! I wonder why no tag is present on SO by this name..

Comment: What do you mean by using C# over HTML5 yet being web based?

Comment: I mean using ASP.net(using C# at back end)

Comment: Guacamole has its own protocol, and a server. You can port the C code.